# Google Analytics: Tracking abandonment and goals for lightbox form

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, seo

I have a series of forms which represent my site's Goals in Google Analytics. Each one redirects to the same page with a query string to differentiate between them (e.g. `/thank-you/?form-name`).

For reasons outside of my control, these forms have to be <del>popups</del> **lightboxes** and while tracking goal completion is as simple as adding a Goal URI for each "thank you" page, I don't know how to track abandonment. Abandonment in this case would be a user clicking "Cancel" instead of "Submit" in the popup.

Does anyone know how I can setup goal abandonment tracking using clicks on the Cancel button? I read about `_gaq.push` for sending custom Events to track, but I couldn't find how to link that to a Goal and track it as an abandonment.

Is this possible? If so, how would I set it up? Can it be linked to a specific goal so I can track the abandonment of each form separately?

---

As an aside, for the situation above would it be better to have separate goals for each form or one goal for all forms differentiated by the goal URI query string?

Comment: Is there analytics code on the pop-up form? Then you should see users exit in the Funnel Visualization report (if you set it correctly)

Comment: Tracking code is on all pages but the popup forms are available on all pages via the WordPress plugin Ninja Forms (with Modal extension) so each page (with "thank you" pages set as goal uri) is tracked.

How would you add tracking code to the popup form so it does it automatically?

Comment: Could you please clarify whether or not your own Google Analytics code is in that pop-up? Do you see the pop-up URL on your Google Analytics reports?

Comment: No, there is no code in the popup itself, only on the page as a whole. The popup is shown, submitted/cancelled via javascript, but are you saying I can track these events as a funnel/abandonment while having the "thank you" page uri as the goal—perhaps using `_gaq.push`? If so, that would be perfect!

Comment: What I'm not sure about - is it a pop-up? Or a lightbox? If it's a pop-up it will have its own URL (normally) then you can just run the analytics code there. Anyhow, I added in an answer the suggested solution.

Comment: My mistake, I meant lightbox. I've commented on your proposed answer, which looks very close to a solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cases where you cannot add the GA code to the form (lightbox, or 3rd party), I would suggest you to create a virtual page view that will simulate a page visit on that form.

Use the following in your JS code that calls the form:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/your-directory/form']);
```

If you use Universal Analytics, then:

```
ga('send', 'pageview', '/your-directory/form');
```

Now the form will be rendered as a pageview, which will appears on your reports and Goals' funnel visualization. Remember to set it as a step in the goal settings:

[image: funnel step]

Comment: This looks promising! The forms are all generated by a plugin so I couldn't put the markup in a specific file, but could I use an #anchor or ?querystring to do the same thing?

Comment: Then I'd suggest you to use "onClick=" event in the <a> that opens the form lightbox. In this event execute the code of the virtual page view. If not by "onClick", a separate Javascript that is executed when this link is clicked, based on ID or class. Easy with JQuery.

Comment: So the link which triggers the lightbox would look like `<a href="#form-name" onclick="ga('send', 'pageview', '#form-name');">Form</a>`. Would I then have to add something to the cancel button in the form for abandonment tracking?

Comment: When you send the virtual pageview, I'm not sure you can use hashtag. You should use a virtual path, such as the one I wrote in the answer above (/your-directory/form). As for the second question, the funnel visualization will work. What you can do however, is to refresh the page view of the page that triggered the lightbox by using ga('send', 'pageview'); This will make sure that the data shows the user clicked the form away, and went back to the page that triggered it. Otherwise, in the funnel visualization it will show as if the user moved from the form, to a page that is two clicks away.

Comment: So you're saying I could use `ga` function to send a pageview for the lightbox using a path that doesn't necessarily exist but represents the form, then use `ga` again on the "Cancel" button so if the confirmation page was a goal and the virtual directory was a funnel step it'll track both conversions and abandonment? Makes sense but am I understanding it correctly?

Comment: Marked as answer and upvoted. Well-deserved, thanks!